# How to decode base64 to image file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, express, base64

I know this question is asked several times, but unfortunately nothing seems to work for me.

I post the src of an img to my node/express. It looks like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA+Q1JF ... UUUUAFFFFAH/2Q==
```

The data is saved in picture. I cut of the data:image-stuff and got the raw base64 and the filetype.

```
    var result = {
        "type":"",
        "data":""
    }

    var matches = picture.match(/^data:image\/([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),response = {};
    result.type = matches[1];
    result.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

    require('fs').writeFile(mediaFolder+'/test.'+result.type, result.data, "binary", function(err){
        res.status(500).send("error");
    });

    res.status(200).send("success");
```

When I try to open the saved image it says: Damaged or too big. I also tried to set the "binary" parameter in the writeFile methode. The client always gets the 200 http status.

I don't know what's wrong with this. I checked the raw base64 String with an online decoder. It worked perfectly.
I logged every string/match and everything looked okay to me.

Any help would be nice to solve this Problem.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is how I send the picture:

```
var base64Image = $('#show-picture').attr('src');
xmlhttp.open("POST","/webapp-ajax",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("picture="+base64Image);
```

Comment: How are you sending the file to the server?

Comment: I use XMLHttpRequest and post it to node/express

Comment: Are you using encodeURIComponent?

Comment: I have edited my Question with the Code of how I send the picture to node.

Comment: Why not just send the image file, why do you mess around with base64 to begin with ?

Comment: Hm, I could try to send the file. The picture is taken from the users smartphone camera and is shown on the webpage with an base64 encoded src. That's why I tried to upload die base64. Maybe I can save the file itself. I'll let you know

Comment: Look into the FormData object, and how to append files to that and send to the server. Not sure how you'd get the image from the users camera, but it sounds very doable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you need to use `encodeUriComponent(base64)` before sending to server.

try sending a JSON object, and parsing the image on the client side.

For example:

```
var mimeType = image.split(';')[0];

var base64 = encodeUriComponent(image.split(',')[1]);

var imageData = {

  "mimeType" : mimeType,

  "src" : base64

}

...

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xmlhttp.send(imageData);
```

Comment: Your solution was right! I modified it a bit for my use and it works like a charm =) If I could I would upvote you!